# ¿Como acceder al contenido de un array asociativo que esta dentro de otro array?

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy intentando crear un array de arrays donde los arrays del interior sean arrays asociativos pero no se como acceder a ellos. Este es mi codigo.

```js
   var meses = {enero:31, febrero:29, marzo:31}
   var año = [];
   año.push(meses);
   console.log(año[meses.enero])
```

De esta manera me sale que enero no esta definido. ¿Alguien sabe como acceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los arrays solo funcionan con índices. Cada elemento de un array tiene un índice que va **desde 0 hasta n-1**, donde **n** es la cantidad de elementos.

Cuando haces:

```
año[meses.enero]
```

En realidad estás diciendo:

```
año[31]
```

¿Por qué? Pues es sencillo. Meses es un **objeto** y en JavaScript los objetos **funcionan como una estructura clave-valor**. La expresión `meses.enero` se traduce a: Tráeme el valor *de la clave enero*.

La manera correcta es:

```js
  var meses = {enero:31, febrero:29, marzo:31}
  var año = [];
  año.push(meses);
  console.log(año[0].enero);
```

Donde `año[0]` referencia al primer (y único) elemento del array año.

**PD:** Trata de no usar caracteres no-compatibles con el inglés para evitar problemas de codificación de texto.

Comment: Perfecto. Asi si que funciona de maravilla. Lo de la ñ a sido un error de principiante. Gracias.

Comment: De nada y bienvenido ;)

Answer (score 0):

Primero deja comentarte que hasta donde yo tengo entendido no puedes declarar una variable mediante una **ñ**, así como tampoco recorrer un apuntados con la **ñ**, ahora bien aquí te dejo un ejemplo del código que solicitas.

*Ojo: Los Arrays no pueden ser asociativos como los estas pensando, solo los Objetos.*

```js
//Declaramos un Objeto, este si puede ser asociativo.
var meses = {"enero":31,"febrero":28,"marzo":31};
//Declaramos un Arreglo, este NO puede ser asociativo
var anos = [];
//Agregamos al array anos los valores del objeto asociativo
anos.push(meses);
//Sacamos por consola el resultado
console.log(anos);
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no se esta accediendo a un `array` que esta dentro de otro `array`,
sino a un objeto que esta dentro de un `array`.
Los `arrays` asociativos llevan la forma:

```
var tabla = new Array();  
tabla['indice1'] = 'valor1';  //esto ya lo puedes meter en otro array
```

Comment: Pedro, bienvenido a SOes. Me parece que la pregunta esta mas orientada a acceder a una parte del arreglo en vez de crearlo. Entiendo que el OP menciona al principio que este en el proceso de creacion, pero al final su pregunta especifica que el probelama es acceder. Si puedes [edit] tu respuesta seria muy bueno, asi mantendremos la calidad del sitio.

Comment: tan solo era una aclaracion pues la pregunta lla estaba respondida